# O que faz a pasta storage no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, framework, storage

Na instalação do Laravel, aparece a pasta storage, mas nunca soube a real função dela. Também é comum existe uma pasta de mesmo nome no CMS opencart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As respostas de @felipe-moereira e @tiago-luz estão incompletas.

Sim a posta storage permite o gerenciamento de uploads e manipulação de arquivos, isto na subpasta `app`, porém em sua estrutura você encontra outras subpastas para outros fins.

Uma descrição completa

### O diretório de armazenamento (storage)

O diretório de storage contém seus modelos Blade compilados, sessões baseadas em arquivo, caches de arquivo e outros arquivos gerados pela estrutura. Este diretório é segregado em diretórios de aplicativos (app), estruturas (framework) e logs.

- O diretório do aplicativo (app) pode ser usado para armazenar quaisquer arquivos gerados por seu aplicativo.
- O diretório da estrutura (framework) é usado para armazenar arquivos e caches gerados pelo framework.
- o diretório de logs contém os arquivos de log (erro, debug, info) do seu aplicativo.

O diretório `storage/app/public` pode ser usado para armazenar arquivos gerados pelo usuário, como avatares de perfil, que devem ser acessíveis ao público. Você deve criar um link simbólico em `public/storage` que aponta para este diretório.

Este link pode ser criado usando o comando `php artisan storage:link`.

Note que por experiência, eu sugiro a criação do link de maneira manual em consoles Linux usando `ln -s /caminho/completo/ate/sistema/storage/app/public /caminho/completo/ate/sistema/public/storage`

Links para documentação Laravel (v.8)

- [Estrutura de diretório](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure)
- [Configuração do Log](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) - que define o comportamento de rotatividade dos arquivos no diretório `storage/logs`
- [Gerenciamento de arquivos no storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)